# jQuery variable to php variable then use it on query

Tags: php, jquery

i have a problem when it comes to retrieving value from jQuery to php.i was able to get the value of my select and pass it to my php but i can't pass it back to php. here is the code...

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
       $("select#months").change(function(event)
       {
         var m=$(this).val();
          $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
           url: "monthly_CRD.php",
           data: {m: m},
               success: function(){alert("updated")}
    });
       });
  });
</script>   


<div>
<select id="months">
  <option value='00'>Month...</option>
      <option value='01'>Jan</option>
      <option value='02'>Feb</option>
      <option value='03'>Mar</option>
      <option value='04'>Apr</option>
    </select>
    <select id="years">
    <?php
     for($yr=10; $yr<=$year; $yr++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$yr."'>".$years[$yr]."</option>";
}
?>
   </select>
</div>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['m'])) 
 {
        $m = $_POST['m'];
        echo $m;
 } else   {echo "fail";} 

?>
```

it keeps on returning fail which means that isset is not working.

Comment: Is the PHP section which checks the POST variable in another file? Or is this the monthly_CRD.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that on page load, it returns `fail`, that is because on page load your `$_POST` array is probably empty.

If you want to know what was returned from your AJAX post, you need your `success` function to accept a parameter (like `data`) that jQuery will fill with the response to your post.
Then in the function body, you can write it to the DOM or your error console.

Comment: A combination of all these answers. Definitely add the quotations "m" is this is syntactically correct for JSON. Also try '{"m", "' + m + '"}' so that your passing it as a string. Also add an error function like- error: function(msg){ //check stuff }

Comment: error function not working.so i guess there's something wrong with the $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

Change `data: {m: m}` to `data: {"m":m}`

Since you are looking at `$_POST['m']` you need to define that key in your JSON. Currently you'd need to look inside `$_POST['03']` if you selected `Mar`

Comment: how would i define it on JSON?

Comment: Sorry I always think JSON when I see a JavaScript object. Just use `{"m": m}` and note the "m" having quotes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure string quoting is optional:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers
If it's the property being set, it's not parsed as a variable. [Only when it's the value being assigned]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an id to an element then just id is enough to select. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
       $("#months").change(function(event)
       {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: "monthly_CRD.php",
           data: { m: $(this).val()},
           success: function(){
              alert("updated")
           }
          });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $("#months").change(function(event)
   {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: "monthly_CRD.php",
       data: '{ "m": "' + $(this).val() + '"}',
       success: function(msg){
          alert(msg)
       },
       error: function(msg) {
          alert("An error happened: " +msg);
       }
      });
  });
```

});

User fiddler of chrome tools to break on either success or error and check the value of the meesage property.

Comment: you need to set a break point on the alert() of the error function and have a look at the msg object. There will be some message from PHP that should hopefully tell you the problem. Also try the modified version of the data: parameter above.

Comment: oh please help me.i've been working for this for about 1 week already.i'm stuck with this drop down. T.t

Comment: If nothing happened your not doing it right. Do you have chrome or firefox? If not, get them. Do you have firebug (FF only) if not get it. Otherwise use Chromes developer toold (which I use). Load the page once. In dev tools or firebug, find the script. In dev tools click to the left hand side of a line of code to set a breakpoint. Not sure for firebug look around. Reload the page without closing dev tools or firebug. It should hit the breakpoint and stop. At which point you will be able to inspect the "msg" variable on the error function and find out what the real problem is.

Comment: can i give you a print screen of what's happening?it's hard to explain what's happening if you can't see it.

Comment: i still can't post any pictures here.

Comment: Move the script out and set a breakpoint on that line of code that fires the alertbox like I said above. I cant help you until you find out what the error is.

Comment: OK the error is 404 not found so monthly_CRD.php does not exist. It is not this file as you said above because this file is called monthly_graph2.php. Put the snippet that handles the POST object in another php file NAMED monthly_CRD.php. Make sure they are in the same folder, then try it again.

Comment: i created a similar file since i can't give you the original link

Comment: The saga continues. Change the URL for the jQuery POST to be monthly_graph2.php and I'll try it again.

Comment: Yeah the code for a php page. Which is exactly what you would expect it to return when you send a request to a php page. If you just want the value, then put the code that handles the post (that is the PHP snippet at the bottom of your OP into a seperate file. Everything is working fine.

Comment: so it means in my original file there is something wrong with my url?

Comment: I don't know because I didn't test that specific page, you gave me another. However if no file called monthly_CRD.php exists then yes that is your first problem. Everything in the test page is working fin anyway so you could just use that page and change the filenames where required. In conclusion, everything works fine.

Comment: the original file is like this i have my index then the dashboard is only included in it.the in the dashboard it's calling the month_CRD.php with the use of jQuery.

Comment: if you are in that page the url in your address bar would be like this http://portal.jimbula.com/crd/admin/index.php?p=reports